# Building gcc 11.2 with jit support requires GMP, MPFR, MPC, ISL recompiled with -fPIC

Tags: gcc, fpic

I'm on a CentOS 7 Linux system where I don't have the root access. So I have to build gcc from source. I want to build gcc 11.2 with the jit support. I invoked
`contrib/download_prerequisites` for GMP, MPFR, MPC and ISL. Then from a build directory I configured gcc using

```
../gcc-11.2.0/configure --prefix=/some/path --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared \
  --enable-host-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-languages=c,c++,jit \
  --disable-multilib
```

then I hit `make`.

It failed with ld errors asking me to recompile `libisl.a, libmpc.a, libmpfr.a, libgmp.a` with `-fPIC`. Right before these errors I saw lots of jit related outputs. I assume jit is behind all of this?

Then I tried adding `CFLAGS=-fPIC` to the above configure command as `../gcc-11.2.0/configure CFLAGS=-fPIC *rest_of_the_options_above*`. The same ld errors were emitted.

I'm aware that those dependencies each has `--with-pic` option to their own configure. But I'm wondering if there is a way to have gcc invoke that for me? If not, does it mean that to build gcc with jit support, one has to build the four dependencies manually with `--with-pic`? Thanks.